# How to print a line above the one with matching pattern in shell?

Tags: shell, grep

I want to print line 1 when the pattern match in line 2. For example -

this is line 1 without pattern
this is line 2 with random pattern

When I do grep on "random", I want to print "this is line 1 without pattern"? 
Any easy trick with grep?

Comment: Use a *before* context.... `grep -B1 "random" file | head -n 1`

Comment: Or maybe `grep -B1 "random" file | grep -v "random"` if it occurs more than once.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell. Second option works for me.

Comment: I put it as an answer so folks can see it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **grep** with a *before context* to find your match and the line before it like this:

```
grep -B1 "random" file
```

then use an inverted **grep** to suppress the lines containing your matches so you are left with just the preceding lines:

```
grep -B1 "random" file | grep -v "random"
```

Comment: That will fail if the word `random` appears on consecutive lines, see the example I include in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35438087/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I agree. Your solution is more accurate - have my vote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
awk '/random/{print prev} {prev=$0}' file
```

In addition to not requiring the search regexp (`random`) to be specified twice, you'll find that it behaves more intuitively/correctly than a `grep | grep -v` solution in some cases, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
this is to be printed
this is also to be printed but contains random 1
this is not to be printed and contains random 2

$ awk '/random/{print prev} {prev=$0}' file
this is to be printed
this is also to be printed but contains random 1

$ grep -B1 "random" file | grep -v "random"
this is to be printed
```